# In Machine Learning, is it okay to add the development set to the training set after development?

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

Usually we train our models on the training set, evaluate them on the development set, make some changes, train and evaluate again, etc. (the development phase), and in the end evaluate once on the test set.

Assume we have little training data. Then, it could make sense to use training AND development set after the development phase. One could estimate hyperparameters as usual and in the end (the final training) add the dev set to the training set, train the model with the previously estimated hyperparameters and evaluate it once on the test set.

Would this be "cheating" in any way? Do people do this, or do they usually leave out the dev set from any training?

Comment: Just to understand... What do you want to achieve? And what do you mean after "development"?

Comment: see my changes; hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's cheating in any way. If it improves your model against real world data and your unseen test data, it should be ok. There are reasons why a training/dev/test set is recommended, but if you have such small training data set, I believe it's a valid strategy. In any case, it's hard to have definitive answer without knowing more details such as nature of data and the task you would like to accomplish. Another approach you might like to have look is data augmentation.
I'd recommend the following course which covers training/dev/test set distribution, among other things: 
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning-projects

Answer (score 1):

Once you decided on the hyperparameter using the dev set, you can use the train + dev to perform the training again. This is method is used quite often.
For example with using GridSearchCV method in sklearn, if you use refit=True, this would perform the training after the hyperparameter search is done. i.e. if cv=4 and refit=True, the model performs training 5 times, (4 times for searching best hyperparameters) + (1 for the final training using the complete training set)